# Mercurial extension for personal repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have this idea for how I would like my version control system to behave, and I thought I'd throw the idea out and see if anyone knows of any existing method to achieve this.
I like mercurial, so that is what I've targeted this question with, but I will gladly hear about other pieces of software that can make this happen.

Ok, so to the problem.
As a researcher I want to version lots of different stuff. This can be code (small scripts or larger applications), manuscripts, data, course work, etc.
I do not want to store all of it in one mega-repository since

1. I want "hg log" to show me only stuff relevant to the current project
2. It is possible that I'd like to publish code elsewhere, and keep history.
3. It just feels wrong...

So my current idea, which I am implementing is to have a directory hierarchy containing different repositories on a central server. Something like this (only stuff marked as hg repo is a repository, everything else is a standard filesystem directory):

```
-- ~/hgrepo/
       --  Projects/
                 --  Project 1 (hg repo)
                 --  Project 2 (hg repo)

       -- Code
                 --  MyCoolApplication
                                  -- MyAppSource (hg repo)
                                  -- SomeExternalPatchedLib (hg repo)

                 --  CodeProject 1 (hg repo)
```

Now, this works fine since I can hack on something and then do `hg clone ssh://my.university.server.com/hgrepo/Code/CodeSample1` and then edit .hg/hgrc and change the default path to the server.
But it is a bit cumbersome.

What I would like is to have an extension which lets me

- List the repository, like `hg repo ls Code/` to show the level below Code/
- Clone using simple paths above (skip tedious ssh:// and server hostname, etc)
- Publish a local repository to the remote repository (i.e. cloning it and changing the default path, while handling errors)

Basically, I suppose it is something like a private, self-hosted, bitbucket/github.
Anyone know of similar systems?

I only have access to a file server via SSH, so I can't run any server applications on the host machine. But I am happy to hear of systems that need one as well, since I might be able to change that if the software is good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket offers private repos for free. Maybe [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) are what you want.